# How to make a query in two different collections in mongoDB? (without using ORM)

Tags: mongodb

Suppose, In MongoDB i have two collections. one is "Students" and the another is "Course".

Student have the document such as

```
{"id":"1","name":"Alex"},..
```

and Course has the document such as

```
{"course_id":"111","course_name":"React"},..
```

and there is a third collection named "students-courses" where i have kept student's id with their corresponding course id. Like this

```
{"student_id":"1","course_id":"111"}
```

i want to make a query with student's `id` so that it gives the output with his/her enrolled course. like this

```
{
  "id": "1", 
  "name":"Alex",
  "taken_courses": [
    {"course_id":"111","course_name":"React"}, 
    {"course_id":"112","course_name":"Vue"}
  ]
}
```

it will be many to many relationship in MongoDB without using ORM. How can i make this query?

Comment: Where is the relationship between student and course stored? you'll need to either store an array of course ids on the student or the otherway around.

Comment: i just want to do all these stuff in GUI (such as Studio 3T)  to make this query... @Kevin Smith

Comment: @NayeemAhmed: what Kevin was asking is: how do you know which students took which courses? You need to store this info somewhere. Do you not store this info?

Comment: I have made  another third collection named "Students-courses" where i have kept students id with their correspondent enrolled course id  @Sergio

Comment: This is done with aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use $loopup with pipeline,

- First $group by `student_id` because we are going to get courses of students, `$push` all `course_id` in `course_ids` for next step - lookup purpose

```
db.StudentCourses.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$student_id",
      course_ids: {
        $push: "$course_id"
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$lookup` with Student Collection and get the student details in `student`
- `$unwind` `student` because its an array and we need only one from group of same student record
- `$project` required fields

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Student",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "student"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$student"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: "$_id",
      name: "$student.name",
      course_ids: 1
    }
  },
```

- `$lookup` Course Collection and get all courses that contains `course_ids`, that we have prepared in above $group
- `$project` the required fields
- course details will store in `taken_courses`

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Course",
      let: {
        cId: "$course_ids"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$course_id",
                "$$cId"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "taken_courses"
    }
  },
```

- `$project` details, removed not required fields

```
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      course_ids: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Working Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/FMZgkyKHPEe

For more details related syntax and usage, check [aggregation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/tutorials/aggregation/)